# Check if specified user belongs to specific group or not

Tags: csom, ssom

I have implemented a site and have added a SharePoint group called "`SG_Uploader`".

In this group, I `ONLY` have one Active Directory group called "`AD_L6`" and there are many users in AD_L6.

If a user comes to site and I want to check if he can upload a document, I use below code which is very simple:

```
SPWeb web = // ...
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["SG_Uploader"];
if (group.ContainsCurrentUser)
{
    // allow user to upload
}
```

Now, I want to do the same thing, not for current user but for a specific user that I have his username. By that mean I want to write a code like

```
SPWeb web = // ...
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["SG_Uploader"];
if (group.ContainsUser(username))
{
    // allow user to upload
}
```

I could not figure out who I can do that. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use DoesUserHavePermissions to check if user has permissions to upload.

```
web.DoesUserHavePermissions(web.CurrentUser,
                   SPBasePermissions.AddListItems);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not sure how this is related to my question. Maybe you misunderstood my question or I don't get your point. It is not about upload. I mentioned upload just as an example.